# Sorting Cross Table in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to sort 3 columns of data in a cross table, by the highest value for the 1st column.  For example:

```
column 1 = project # identifier
column 2 = project customer name
column 3 = project customer location
value = project £ value
```

I need to show all 3 columns - but the first line should be the highest value project value, descending below. I understand that I could concatenate the 3 columns - but visually, I ma trying to maintain each column separately.

Any ideas very gratefully appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a cross table you can just click on the column header to sort it. The columns sort independently of each other though, so you can't sort by Column A, then B, then C like you can in Excel and maintain dependence.

Comment: Thanks. I've just found out this feature is available in version 7.7

Comment: Interesting. I'm on 7.5 at the moment @Grant